# Upvote (like) function using mongodb $push and $pull

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to create like / unlike function for my project which is a book review app. User should be able to like or un-like (remove like vote) a given review, and they can should be limited to only one like per review.

I am working with mongodb and reviews documents looks like this in this case:

```
_id: ObjectId()
title: string
author:
publication_year: string
type: string
genre: string
cover: string 
summary: string
review: string
added_by: string
upvote: array #(list of users that liked the review)
```

So the function I am trying to build should first of all check if user username is in the array, if yes it should pull/ delete record (username) if not it should push the record in the array.

This is what I have now but I cannot make it work:

```
@app.route('/upvote/<review_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upvote(review_id):

    username = current_user.get_id()

    upvoted = mongo.db.reviews.find( { '_id' : ObjectId(review_id) },
                                        { 'upvote' : { '$elemMatch': 
                                            { 'username' : username } } } ).count()

    if upvoted > 0:
        mongo.db.reviews.update({ "_id": ObjectId(review_id) },
                                        { '$pull': 
                                            { 'upvote': 
                                                {'username': username} } } )
    else:
        mongo.db.reviews.update({ "_id": ObjectId(review_id) }, 
                                        { '$push': 
                                            { 'upvote': 
                                            {'username': username}  } } )

    return redirect(url_for('view_review', review_id=review_id))
```

Could you please advise what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Double checking upvote looks like this: 
 `upvote: [ {username: 'userA', otherfld: ...}, {username: 'userB', otherfld}, ...]`
?

Comment: Upvote only lists usernames, there are no other fields, so it looks like this: upvote: [ {username: 'userA', {username: 'userB'} ]

Answer (score 0):

Given this input:

```
var r = [
{"_id": 0, upvote: [ {username: "A"}, {username: "B"} ] },
{"_id": 1, upvote: [ {username: "C"}, {username: "D"} ] },
{"_id": 2, upvote: [ {username: "A"}, {username: "D"} ] }
 ];
```

Then with `var reviewId = 2; var username = "C";` it adds `C` to the upvote array since it is not there:

```
var d = db.foo.findOne({_id:reviewId, "upvote.username":username});
if(d != null) {
    // Found, so pull it out:                                                             
    rc = db.foo.update({ "_id": reviewId},
                  { '$pull': { 'upvote': {'username': username}}});
} else {
    // Not found, so add it:                                                              
    rc = db.foo.update({ "_id": reviewId},
                  { '$push': { 'upvote': {'username': username}}});
}
```

yields:

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "upvote" : [
        {
            "username" : "A"
        },
        {
            "username" : "D"
        },
        {
            "username" : "C"
        }
    ]
}
```

Calling it again does the opposite.  `C` is found so it is pulled from the array.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out I was using old Pymongo function `count()` instead of  of `count_documents()`. So my code should be like this:

`@app.route('/upvote/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upvote(review_id):

```
username = current_user.username


match_count = mongo.db.reviews.count_documents({
    '_id' : ObjectId(review_id),
    'upvote': {'$elemMatch': { "username": username}},
})

if match_count > 0:
    print("not equal to 0")
    mongo.db.reviews.update({ "_id": ObjectId(review_id) },
                                    { '$pull':
                                        { 'upvote':
                                        {'username': username}  } } )

else:
    print("equal to 0")
    mongo.db.reviews.update({ "_id": ObjectId(review_id) },
                                    { '$push':
                                        { 'upvote':
                                        {'username': username}  } } )

return redirect(url_for('view_review', review_id=review_id))`
```